# How to set multiple strings for Python Enum?

Tags: python, enums, multivalue

I want to define multiple strings for an enum variable and compare the variable either against a string or an enum type. I am currently doing the following:

```py
from enum import Enum


class Ordinal(str, Enum):
    NORTH = ['north', 'NORTH', 'n']
    SOUTH = ['south', 'SOUTH', 's']


input_by_user_1 = 'n'
input_by_user_2 = Ordinal.NORTH
print(input_by_user_1 in Ordinal.NORTH)  #True
print(input_by_user_2 in Ordinal.NORTH)  #True
print(input_by_user_1 == Ordinal.NORTH)  #False
print(input_by_user_2 == Ordinal.NORTH)  #True
```

However, I do not find the `in` key word nice to understand. I would rather prefer the option using `==` but this does not work because I defined a list. Is there a better way to do that?

**Solution:**

The answer was to use the MultiValueEnum class. Then I can use the following code:

```py
from aenum import MultiValueEnum


class Ordinal(MultiValueEnum):
    NORTH = 'north', 'NORTH', 'n'
    SOUTH = 'south', 'SOUTH', 's'


input_by_user_1 = 'n'
input_by_user_2 = Ordinal.NORTH
print(Ordinal(input_by_user_1) == Ordinal.NORTH)  #True
print(Ordinal(input_by_user_2) == Ordinal.NORTH)  #True
```

Answer (score -1):

You can override the equality operator!

```py
from enum import Enum

class Ordinal(str, Enum):
    NORTH = ['north', 'NORTH', 'n']
    SOUTH = ['south', 'SOUTH', 's']
    
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return other in self.__dict__['_value_']
```

Comment: Doing this makes `Ordinal.NORTH == Ordinal.NORTH` false.

Comment: Actually, it appears to work in that case. Check out my [repl](https://repl.it/join/omspjiqf-nickkahlor)

Comment: Ah, right -- I missed that `Ordinal` inherits from `str` -- which means that the value of `Ordinal.NORTH` is `"['north', 'NORTH', 'n']"`.  So the OP has bigger problems than just equality.

Comment: If I were in OP's shoes I would probably just normalize the user input and avoid this type of thing all together ¯\_(ツ)_/¯